# unable to write to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app which can write to firebase database on button click.
The app is working on emulator but it's not working on my physical device.
Here's the main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Firebase fled1;
Button on;
Button off;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        on=  findViewById(R.id.on);
        off=  findViewById(R.id.off);

        on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                fled1 = new Firebase("https://iotapp-6y3n8.firebaseio.com/");
                Firebase fled1Child = fled1.child("S1");
                fled1Child.setValue("1");
            }
        });

        off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fled1 = new Firebase("https://iotapp-6y3n8.firebaseio.com/");   
                Firebase fled1Child = fled1.child("S1");
                fled1Child.setValue("0");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's my manifest file I have added all the permissions required:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lalitahuja.iotbutton">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.lalitahuja.iotbutton.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the build Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lalitahuja.iotbutton"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error I'm getting:

E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
W/MessengerIpcClient: Timing out request: 1
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
W/MessengerIpcClient: Timing out request: 2
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
W/MessengerIpcClient: Timing out request: 3
W/MessengerIpcClient: Received response for unknown request: 3
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
W/MessengerIpcClient: Received response for unknown request: 1
W/MessengerIpcClient: Received response for unknown request: 2

Comment: Why are you using a really old version of the Firebase SDK?  `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2` in addition to the newer one `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0`?  Don't use the old one.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated the firebase sdk but I'm still getting the 
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
Error any idea what might be causing this?